# ¿Como puedo imprimir el resultado de una función en otra función pero con Atributo especifico?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo tres clases clases creadas: principal, personaje y transformación.

```
//Estos son los atributos de Personaje:

private String tipo;
private String Nombre;
private String Lugar_de_Nacimiento;
private int Edad;
private double Estatura;
private double Nivel_de_pelea;
private transformacion Transformacion;

//estos son los atributos de Transformacion:

private int Codigo;
private String Nombre;
private String Cambio_de_Apariencia;
private int multi_poder;

//Mi problema es cuando creo una función que guarde el resultado de la
// "pelea de dos personajes" teniendo encuenta el que tenga mayor "nivel de 
//poder" ese sera el ganador:

public Personaje pelear(Personaje contrincante)
{
    if(this.getNivel_de_pelea()>contrincante.getNivel_de_pelea())
    {
    return this;
    }
  else
{
    return contrincante;
}
}

//Quiero aclarar que en mi "clase principal" 
//YA tengo creado TODOS los OBJETOS necesarios.

//Vista la función anterior quisiera saber como puedo imprimir "**EL 
//NOMBRE**" del ganador de dicha "pelea":

public void imprimir_Ganador()
{
System.out.println("Nombre del Ganador: "+ ¿?);
}
```

Comment: Supongo, según los comentarios, que devuelves al ganador desde el método `pelear`... Dado que el objeto devuelto es del tipo `Personaje`, sólo tienes que invocar al *getter*  de `Personaje` para obtener el nombre. Dado que no muestras esa clase, no podría decirte exactamente cómo se llama ese método, imaginemos que es `getName`, entonces harías algo como esto: `Personaje contrincante=new Personaje(...); Personaje ganador = objetoDondeEstaPelear.pelear(contrincante); System.out.println("Nombre del Ganador:  "+ganador.getName());` A mi me parece que tienes problemas organizando tu modelo.

Comment: Si quieres adaptar tu modelo de datos a la realidad, lo correcto sería tener una clase `Pelea` que recibiera en el constructor dos o más objetos del tipo `Personaje` y demás miembros propios de una pelea. Esa clase tendría un método `getGanador` que retornaría un objeto del tipo `Personaje` que sería el ganador de la pelea y sobre ese objeto puedes invocar cualquiera de sus *getter*.

Comment: No seria incorrecto que pelear estuviera en la clase personaje.. podria ser una sobreescritura en realidad porque cada uno podria tener buffs o cosas que hicieran que su forma de pelear fuera diferente.. pero eso ya es otro tema... @A.Cedano

Comment: @gbianchi no sé lo que es *buffs*. Si fuera yo incorporaría una clase `Pelea`, no le veo sentido a poner en `Personaje` un método `pelear` (no necesariamente todos los personajes pelean). Además es probable que haya otras propiedades constitutivas de una pelea que se estén incluyendo erróneamente y por este mismo motivo, en `Personaje`. ¿El ganador dónde se decide en un `Personaje` o en una `Pelea`? El ganador es un `Personaje` que viene dado por una `Pelea`. Con ese razonamiento lógico es suficiente para tener claras las cosas, creo yo.

Comment: @A.Cedano podemos pasarnos toda la tarde discutiendo.. y ninguno de los dos tendra la razon ;). buffs se le dice a cuando un personaje tiene elementos (poderes, armaduras, lo que sea) que bajan o suben el poder de su ataque. O lo que sea.. igual, es una discusion sin mucho sentido.. tu razonamiento es totalmente logico y valido...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu funcion pelear, que seguramente este dentro de la clase personaje, hace lo mismo que vos queres hacer en la función imprimir_Ganador.

Fijate que para imprimir un ganador, tenes que saber que "objeto" gano, y eso te lo devuelve la funcion pelear.

Entonces, en tu codigo, podrias obtener el "objeto" que gano, y pasarselo a la funcion imprimir.

Digamos que estamos parados en tu clase principal.

Entonces tendrias algo asi:

```
private Personaje personaje1;
private Personaje personaje2;
...
private Personaje Ganador = personaje1.pelear(personaje2);
...
imprimir_Ganador(Ganador);

public void imprimir_Ganador(Personaje p)
{
    System.out.println("Nombre del Ganador: "+ p.Nombre); //o el get que corresponda
}
```